# Ceiling fan that won’t turn off

Tags: electrical

I have a ceiling fan that when I turn on with my remote the light will come on as well as the fan.

However, with the remote I can control the light off or on but the fan, even on zero, continues to run and will not turn off. (*remote settings for fan are 0 - 1 - 2 - 3.*)

Comment: How did it get that way? Can you show us pix of the wiring above the fan?

Comment: What kind of wall switch does it have, does the behavior of the remote stay the same with the wall switch in different modes.

Comment: What make and model is your fan? Can you post photos of the wiring involved please?